# Store class instance in the dom?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to store initialized class in the DOM for later use?

```
 let lion1 = new Animal("lion","5","100lb");
 let lion2 = new Animal("lion","7","80lb");
 document.getElementById("lion1").append(lion1);
 document.getElementById("lion2").append(lion2);
```

then later

```
lion1 = document.getElementById("lion1").getFirst();
lion1.roar()
lion2 = document.getElementById("lion2").getFirst();
lion2.roar()
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on later usage? Later like coming back in to a web app after closing the browser or how? Thanks!

Comment: why not using [IndexedDB_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? also you can use [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: @Mamoun i was reading about local storage - not a bad idea, post it as an answere, i will accept it.

Comment: @user648026, I posted it as answer. glad to help!

Comment: Maybe you asking about something that swiper.js do? After you initialize it, you can access to his methods and params simply query the dom element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a task I would suggest using [IndexedDB_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), also you can use [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)